# can a javascript module be more than 1 file by definition or by convention?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, module

This question seems to be common to many. I couldn't find a definitive answer on the web. for example this is AMD's definition of a module:

> Definition: how to encapsulate a piece of code into a useful unit, and
>   how to register its capability/export a value for the module.

Would appreciate someone with more experience working with different module formats to answer or comment!

Comment: The pattern I've seen most these days is to write a module/package in multiple files and then use babel/webpack to make it into a single module for use in a web browser. That way you can use multiple files, es6 syntax, etc, all while avoiding problems with browser compatibility and global namespace pollution.

Comment: ES6 modules are single files.